# Michaelis–Menten kinetics using Tau-Leaping

Tags: simulation, chemistry

I am trying to implement Michaelis–Menten kinetics using Tau-Leaping. It works fine as expected. Only issue here is when substrate reaches zero the algorithm stop since PoissonDistribution[0]  gives error. What I want is if  #[[3]] = 0, then set #[[3]] = 1 and run until #[[4]]>0. I don't know how to use if condition here. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
With[{τ = 0.001, k1 = 1.1, k2 = 0.1, k3 = 0.8, e = 200, s = 200, c = 1, p = 1},
  sim = 
    NestWhileList[
      ({Δp1, Δp2, Δp3} = 
          {RandomVariate @ PoissonDistribution[τ k1  #[[2]] #[[3]]], 
           RandomVariate @ PoissonDistribution[τ k2  #[[4]]], 
           RandomVariate @ PoissonDistribution[τ k3  #[[4]]]};
        {#[[1]] + τ, 
         #[[2]] - Δp1 + Δp2 + Δp3, 
         #[[3]] - Δp1 + Δp2, 
         #[[4]] + Δp1 - Δp2 - Δp3, #[[5]] +Δp3}) &, 
    {0, e, s, c, p}, 
    #[[3]] > 0 &]];

{t, e, s, c, p} = Transpose @ sim;

ListStepPlot[
  {Transpose @ {t, e}, Transpose @ {t, s}, Transpose @ {t, c}, Transpose@{t, p}}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Enzyme", "Substrate", "Complex", " Product"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a `SeedRandom` that exhibits the failure?  I can't reproduce the problem. (Not that I could solve the issue if I could reproduce the problem....)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added SeedRandom. The code produce the image that I have attached but it stop in a short time before complex reach to zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hack #1: add 10^-100 to the argument of `PoissonDistribution`.  This won't appreciably affect the rates, but will prevent `PoissonDistribution[0]` from occurring.

This reveals another potential problem: reactions can use more than the number of molecules that exist, leading to negative numbers, which then leads to problems with negative arguments to `PoissonDistribution`.

Hack #2: use `Min` to make sure reactions don't consume more reactants than exist.  (Just thought of this one, please comment if you see any problems with it).

Together:

```
With[{τ = 0.001, k1 = 1.1, k2 = 0.1, k3 = 0.8, e = 200, s = 200, 
  c = 1, p = 1, eps = 10^-100}, 
  sim = NestWhileList[({Δp1, Δp2, Δp3} = {
    Min[{RandomVariate@PoissonDistribution[eps + τ k1 #[[2]] #[[3]]],
      #[[2]], #[[3]]}],
    Min[{RandomVariate@PoissonDistribution[eps + τ k2 #[[4]]],
      #[[4]]}],
    Min[{RandomVariate@PoissonDistribution[eps + τ k3 #[[4]]],
      #[[4]]}]};
    {#[[1]] + τ, #[[2]] - Δp1 + Δp2 + Δp3, #[[3]] - Δp1 + Δp2,
     #[[4]] + Δp1 - Δp2 - Δp3, #[[5]] + Δp3}) &,
    {0, e, s, c, p}, #[[4]] > 0 &]
];

{t, e, s, c, p} = Transpose@sim;

ListStepPlot[{Transpose@{t, e}, Transpose@{t, s}, Transpose@{t, c}, 
  Transpose@{t, p}}, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Enzyme", "Substrate", "Complex", " Product"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works like a charm!!! Thanks..